# Shortest Path to Cover All nodes in a graph given a starting and ending node

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I am trying to solve a problem in which there is an undirected graph with positive weighted edges and I need to find the shortest path that covers all the nodes exactly once given the start and end node. In addition the graph is complete(each node is connected to all the other nodes in the graph).
I have tried searching for an algorithm that could solve this problem but I haven't found one that solves this problem. This is not exactly the traveling sales man problem because of the restriction of the start and end node. I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: google travelling salesman problem

Comment: I already did that, but I haven't found an algorithm that can calculate a good approximation of my problem. The traveling salesman is to find a path that comes back to the start point. I don't want to come back to the start point, the path has to finish at the end point.

Comment: travelling salesman is in NP and well-studied. it's for you to do the work.

Comment: Given the graph is complete, solve TSP and remove one edge.

Comment: @stark How are you going to get it to end at the given end vertex?

Comment: Solve TSP with the constraint that start and end are connected by an edge. Use simulated annealing or whatever.  Then remove that edge.  Wah-la.

Comment: thanks for the help @stark, can you elaborate more, I am kind of a newb in graph algorithms

Comment: @stark That won't work because the TSP tour is not guaranteed to take the edge from the start to the end.

Comment: @AndyJones As I said, you have to add that as a constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're starting at node `S` and ending at `T`, add a dummy node `D` that has zero-weight  edges to only `S` and `T`. Find an optimal travelling salesman tour on this graph, then remove the dummy node from the tour to get your path.

If you'd like to preserve the graph's completeness property, you can implement the above by adding the dummy node with zero-weight edges to `S` and `T`, and with edges to all other nodes having weights larger than the sum of the weights of the `n` heaviest edges in the graph. For practical purposes, this means setting their weights to `Integer.Max` or similar.